# Is it possible to manually call the constructor of a class in C++?

Tags: c++

The most common way of creating an object of a class is by using the `new` keyword. It also calls the constructor.
But if we used the `malloc` function to create the object, the constructor doesn't get called. Is it still possible to manually call the constructor after creating the object using `malloc`?

Comment: Well, you could use placement new. Not sure what you're after specifically, though, because it's basically just reimplementing `new`.

Comment: Yes, it's called [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)

Comment: I would imagine creating objects on the stack is more common than creating them dynamically.

Comment: "The most common way of creating an object of a class is by using the new keyword". Not correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want to call the constructor an a piece of memory created by `malloc`.  This is possible and is called placement new

```
void* pMemory = malloc(sizeof(C));
C* pValue = new (pMemory) C();
```

Comment: Why mixing C functionality with C++?  Wouldn't is be better to use something like this for allocation: `void* pMemory = new char[sizeof(C)]`

Comment: _Technically_ That only indirectly calls the constructor.  Might be worth mentioning

Comment: @icepack: In what way would that be better? Looks a bit odd to me. `malloc` does exactly what is wanted in this case, and is appropriately named for it, memory allocation.  You use `new char[]` when you want an array of char, which is not desired in this case.

Comment: @icepack the OP specifically mentioned `malloc` in the question hence I used it in the example

Comment: @JaredPar Sorry, missed that part.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Maybe it's a different point of view but I'm used to look at array of char just as a raw buffer (can be typedef'ed to something like BYTE for better verbosity) and malloc is something from the old C

Comment: @Jared: Could you elaborate on the usage of the new keyword in your code snippet? How does new behave differently in this usage?

Comment: @reza.safiyat plain old new consists of 2 operations: 1) allocate memory and 2) initialize the object.  The form of new I used here does only the second part because the memory to use is passed as an explicit parameter

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly call the constructor as you would some other function because the constructor has no name.

What you can to is to use placement new, and this will call your constructor on the memory provided to placement new.

Comment: uhm. The constructor does have a name.

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan - Quoting directly from the C++ standard (pick any version), "**Constructors do not have names.**" This wording has remained unchanged since the very first release of the C++ standard. Constructors do of course have name-mangled names, but only the implementation is allowed to use those names.

Comment: Well naturally c++ names are mangled. But mangled names has nothing to do with writing cpp code. Cpp ctor has a name. So does the dtor. Which is the name of its class.

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan - I specifically quoted from the standard. **Constructors do not have names.** You can write code that directly calls other member functions (including the destructor) because those other member function do have names. The only way to call the constructor is indirectly via `new`.

Comment: Yes it is true that you cant call the ctor without placement new. But that doesnt mean it has no name. If it had no name, how could we declare it and define it out of line?